# ¿como validar si mi aplicativo fue ejecutado con permisos de administrador desde C#?

Tags: c#, permisos

Actualmente realice un programa en c# , el cual funciona bien, el problema es que cuando trata de modificar un archivo por ejemplo en la carpeta "C:/archivos de programa" , no realiza su funcion adecuadamente a menos que desde un inicio se ejecutara con permisos de administrador, mis dudas son las siguientes:

1. Hay alguna forma que cuando se ejecute el programar validar si fue ejecutado con permisos de administrador y si no es asi solicitarlos
   2.-Bloquear cierts funciones dependiendo si fue ejecutado el con permisos de administrador y/0 solicitarlos desde la aplicacion para escalar a esos permisos

Gracias.